# Passing a Jquery value to PHP Query

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a JQGrid with a OndblClickRow function as follows:

```
    ondblClickRow: function(rowid)
    {
        rowData = $("#bookings").getRowData(rowid);
                    var brData = rowData['bookref'];
                    console.log(brData);



        getGridRow(brData);

        //$("#cp-bookings-dialog").dialog({ hide: 'slide', height: 625, width: 733, title: 'Booking Reference: - '+ brData});
    },
```

This is being passed to the following function:

```
function getGridRow(brData) {

    $.post("bookings-dialog.php", { 'rowdata': brData } );
               $("#cp-bookings-dialog").load('bookings-dialog.php').dialog({ show: "slide", hide: 'slide', height: 625, width: 733, title: 'Booking Reference: - '+ brData});
    ,
```

Which loads the bookings.dialog.php page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Title</title>
<?php

set_include_path($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/onlinebookingv4/scripts/php/");
require_once('models/sql.php');

require_once('models/bookingdocket.php');



    $pdo = new SQL();
    $dbh = $pdo->connect(Database::$serverIP, Database::$serverPort, Database::$dbName, Database::$user, Database::$pass);

    try {
           $rowdata = $_POST['rowdata'];
           $query = ("SELECT * FROM tblbookings WHERE bookref = '$rowdata'");

        $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);

        $stmt->execute();

        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);

           BookingDocket::set_id($row['id']);
           BookingDocket::set_bookref($row['bookref']);
           BookingDocket::set_bookdate($row['bookingdate']);
           BookingDocket::set_returndate($row['returndate']);
           BookingDocket::set_journeytype($row['journeytype']);
           BookingDocket::set_passtel($row['passengertel']);
           BookingDocket::set_returndate($row['returndate']);



        $stmt->closeCursor();

    }

    catch (PDOException $pe) {
        die("Error: " .$pe->getMessage(). " Query: ".$stmt->queryString);
    }

    $dbh = null;





?>
</head>

<body>
<div class="cp-tiles-wrapper-dlg">

<div class="cp-booking-info left">

    <p class="pno-margin">Booking Date: &nbsp;<strong>Booking Reference is = <? echo BookingDocket::get_bookref(); ?></strong></p>
    <p class="pno-margin">Query =  &nbsp;<strong><? echo $query; ?></strong></p>
    <p class="pno-margin">Journey: &nbsp;<strong></strong></p>
    <p class="pno-margin">Passenger Tel: &nbsp;<strong></strong></p>
    <p class="pno-margin">E-mail: &nbsp;<strong></strong></p>

</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

What I am trying to do is pass 'brData' which is the booking reference to bookings-dialog.php so that I can select all bookings from the database by booking reference.

At the moment, when I double click a row, in firebug console I get the following:

POST bookings-dialog.php which is showing `SELECT * FROM tblbookings WHERE bookref = 'BR1278'` which is correct

But it is also showing:

GET bookings-dialog.php which is showing `SELECT * FROM tblbookings WHERE bookref = ''`

To me it looks like this is being overridden somehow, I'm probably wrong.

Anybody have any idea how I can get this to work?

Comment: Well what did you expect? Sure, you pass data over, but before you even get the data back you call some random load function to load that file. That is the GET request yuo're seeing. What you really want is to manipulate the data returned in the `callback function` of the `.post()` you nivoke.

Comment: How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Well, firstly. You should use REST based practices. You are not looking to post the data, you are looking to GET the data. POST is for when you want to send data over to update either a database or a file. GET Is when you want to send data over, perform a comparison, and send data back to the user.

Answer (score 0):

We don't want to send back HTML, we want to send back something like JSON. our `#cp-bookings-dialog` element should have a HTML structure that looks like ->

```
<div id="cp-bookings-dialog">
  <div class="cp-tiles-wrapper-dlg">
    <div class="cp-booking-info left">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then we send our data to the server. Your existing code is actually fine, my comment was assuming a different type of action.

```
$.post("bookings-dialog.php", { 'rowdata': brData } );
```

This is where I have to make assumptions. After you do your `set_var($_POST['var'])` on your `BookingDocket` class, we should just return a JSON encoded array of key:value pairs to be parsed in our browser, and used to update the information in the dialog.

```
//for example, only showing the last two...
BookingDocket::set_passtel($row['passengertel']);
BookingDocket::set_returndate($row['returndate']);

//create a scope of variables to prepare and return
$booking_date = BookingDocket::get_bookref();
//query is already set, omitting it.
//making assumptions about data I cannot see
$journey = BookingDocket::get_journey();
$pass_tel = BookingDocket::get_tel();
$email = BookingDocket::get_email();

//formatting here is for example and not live usage
return json_encode(array("date" => $booking_data, 
                         "query" => $query, 
                         "journey" => $journey, 
                         "pass_tel" => $pass_tel, 
                         "email" => $email
                         )
                  );
```

So now we're returning a JSON encoded array, let's go back to the $.post method and see what we can do now.

```
//I prefer to write things out with $.ajax
$.ajax({
  url: 'booking-dialog.php',
  data: {'rowdata' : brData },
  dataType: 'json', //this is what we expect our returned data as
  success: function(data){
    //empty our dialog so we don't end up with duplicate content
    $('.cp-booking-info').empty();
    //we have told the browser to expect JSON back, no need to do any parsing
    //the date
    $('.cp-booking-info').append('<p class="pno-margin">Booking Date: '+data.date+'</p>');
    //the query
    $('.cp-booking-info').append('<p class="pno-margin">Query: '+data.query+'</p>');
    //the journey
    $('.cp-booking-info').append('<p class="pno-margin">Journey: '+data.journey+'</p>');
    //thepassenger tel
    $('.cp-booking-info').append('<p class="pno-margin">Passenger Tel: '+data.pass_tel+'</p>');
    //the email
    $('.cp-booking-info').append('<p class="pno-margin">Email: '+data.email+'</p>');

    //now let's manipulate our dialog and open it.
    $("#cp-bookings-dialog").dialog({ 
      show: "slide", 
      hide: 'slide', 
      height: 625, 
      width: 733, 
      title: 'Booking Reference: - '+ brData
    });
  }

});
```

This is the quickest mockup I could make of how I would imagine your system to work.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm not sure why though but when I have the dataType set to 'json' it fails. When it is set to text or xml though it works? Any ideas?

Comment: @nsilva check the console for errors, I'm going to assume it has to do with the headers being sent back from the server, or perhaps it's an issue with the structure of the JSON object.